# Wordpress custom sidebar template not active

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I am working on a wordpress site (my first), where I want to use a specific sidebar for a specific page template. The sidebar is not the regular widget area, but a template (sidebar-2.php) that calls another template (boeking.php) of a form.

I used the default page.php and sidebar.php as a starting point, copied almost everything, and thus created a template for the page (reisbeschrijving.php) that calls sidebar-2 by using `get_sidebar('2')`. I also created a template sidebar-2.php:

It worked at first, but while I was working on another part of the website it stopped working all of a sudden. The page template works fine, but it doesn't load the sidebar-2, because the `is_active_sidebar()` returns false. However, I don't know why it returns false. When I call `get_sidebar()` (default) in reisbeschrijving.php, it does display sidebar.php, and `is_active_sidebar()` returns true. If I remove the if `is_active_sidebar()` clause, sidebar-2 displays just fine. both sidebar.php and sidebar-2.php are in the same folder (of the child theme).

Did I miss something? Should I register the new sidebar-2 template somewhere in the header or something? I know that this is the case for the custom dynamic sidebars with widget area's, but this is an altogether new template and I thought I wouldn't have to (I tried anyway, but to no avail).
Any hints on why `is_active_sidebar` returns 'false' on my second sidebar is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to register your sidebar in your functions.php file. Look at `register_sidebar()` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1st Register sidebar - functions.php

```
function my_custom_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar(
        array (
            'name' => __( 'Custom', 'your-theme-domain' ),
            'id' => 'custom-side-bar',
            'description' => __( 'Custom Sidebar', 'your-theme-domain' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-content">',
            'after_widget' => "</div>",
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_custom_sidebar' );
```

2. Put this code in template

   if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ) ) :
       dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' );
   endif;

This will work 100%

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I tried to register it again and changed the code in the sidebar-2 template to the one Ravi indicated, but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?